# Cross-browser issue while using jQuery Mobile

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am using PhoneGap, in which we are allowed to use jQuery/JavaScript for manipulation operations. I make an Ajax request to a webservice I wrote in CakePHP, sending 3 things: id (from the address bar), and latitude and longitude (from HTML5 geolocation).

Now the problem is the same webservice gives correct data in the Firefox while in other browsers for the same `lat` and `long` it says "no data".

I used crossdomain in the Ajax request and I am using the POST method.

this is the request code

```
var request= $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: 'url',

            data:{ id: localStorage.getItem("id"), latitude: localStorage.latitude,longitude: localStorage.longitude},
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "xml",
            cache: false
       });
request.done(function (data){
//show data
});
request.fail(function (data){
alert('error');
});
```

Comment: Do you use exactly the same script or you do a mobile detection before and adapt script to the return? Maybe you could write the Ajax code to help us aswering

Comment: i am not that much expert, and didnot got your point as well, i am using jquery mobile, this is a website on which i facing issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got the error and solved it by googling then...... the problem was javascript's split function in other browsers specially in chrome, integer was converted to alphabet i dont know why so i used this function to get the desired value........

```
function getUrlVars() {
                        var vars = {};
                        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
                            vars[key] = value;
                        });
                        return vars;
                    }
                    var first = getUrlVars()["id"];
```

and now if i alert(first); it will give me integer value, and webservice will return related records to the value

Answer (score 0):

Try this test

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
  // API is working
} else {
  // no support
}
```

It will tell you if thebrowser you are using accept geolocation API.

Comment: So we need to see your Ajax request to answer. Maybe there is a bug inside

Comment: Have you tried to use this to see in firebug if the request was sent successfully? http://chrispederick.com/work/user-agent-switcher/

Comment: I don't mean the one from your desktop, try to change the user_agent and look at the request